# how can i search sub string from original string

Tags: android

```
String ORIGINAL = "This is my demo string";
String search = "demo";
```

I want to get the result as true or false if "demo" is exits into ORIGINAL then result is true otherwise return false

Comment: Use `contains`? `indexOf`? Did you even look at the String API?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(ORIGINAL.contains(search))
     //found
else
    //not found
```